# Import Bulk JSON Data into an ArangoDB Cluster

Tags: arangodb

I am having trouble importing 300M+ JSON records into an ArangoDB cluster.   I understand that `_api/import` is not currently supported in clusters, but is there a workaround?

With the cluster running, I attempted to connect to one of the DB instances directly, and used `arangoimp` to load the data.  This approach seemingly completes without an error. However the uploaded data is nowhere to be found.

Comment: What is the command line you used to import it? Maybe it's in the _system database?

Comment: I tried every approach imaginable - using the `arangoimp` command line tool, using the Upload button in the collection list page of the web app GUI, and calling the python `import_bulk` -- all to no avail.  Have you had any success in importing bulk data into an arangodb cluster collection?

Comment: @SandroGvelesiani I used python-arango `import_bulk`, which caused error "http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response". Did you have the same error? Did you solve your problem?